# not able to access to localhost

Tags: ubuntu, localhost

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop.

I was develping websites without any problem so far.

Then suddenly I am not able to access any website in localhost.

Even http://localhost/phpinfo.php does not show.

I reinstalled apache but it is the same result.

I am able to access localhost/phpmyadmin.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you substitute 127.0.0.1 for localhost ?

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn

```
 ServerName localhost
```

And it works now.

:-)